# Retain Password Field Value on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

Right now I have an asp:Wizard with 3 Steps.

1. Create User
2. Form to Email
3. Summary of Fields

When the finish button is clicked on the third step I would like to Create the user and send the form. I have the logic for this written but the only problem I have is the when the next button is pressed on a wizard, a PostBack occurs and my password field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" Width="70%" runat="server" />
```

Does not retain its value.

What would you suggest would be the most secure and practical method for me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably develop a class representing the data that will be created by the wizard:

```
public class WizardForm
{
    public User NewUser {get;set;}
    public Form FormToEmail {get;set;}
}
```

Then on each step through the wizard I'd update this class and store it in session:

```
WizardForm form = Session["WizardForm"] as WizardForm;
if (form == null)
{  
     form = new WizardForm();
     Session["WizardForm"] = form;
}

form.User.Password = txtPassword.Text; // etc
```

Or you could just store the password in Session and retrieve it later:

```
Session["WizardPassword"] = txtPassword.Text;
string password = Session["WizardPassword"].ToString();
```

Comment: So basically create an object to store each step of the wizard as it is completed then take the object and do whatever you want to do with it when the finish button is clicked?

Comment: as for storing the password in session. Is this a secure method or would I also have to go about encrypting the password?

Comment: @GaryDevenay - Session variables are not something people can get
to from the client side unless you send them to them. Should be secure enough, but I'm not an expect on security by a long shot.

Comment: Mine doesn't retain it. I save it using session and then assign it but it goes back to default. Is it because I am using placeholder?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to create any classes; just use the following line of code in your `page_load` method:

```
YourTextBoxName.Attributes["value"] = YourTextBoxName.Text ;
```

This should probably solve this problem.

Comment: If you put the .Text value in "YourTextBoxName.Attributes["value"] = txtPassword.Text;" your password will be viewable in the page source.

Comment: @wotney Your password will still be easy to find you could just  change type="password" for "text" in source. I Think that OP  solutions would always involve easy source page password finding, since it will be on client side.

Answer (score 1):

This beavior is built in to the asp.net TextBox control when in Password mode.  If you want different behavior you can either create your own password server control or use a normal HTML input control with runat="server".  You could also just save the password when the user progresses to the next wizard step and then display a place holder instead of the text box.  In order to change or edit thet password the user has to go back to the relevant wizard step.