# TextBox with property TextMode = Password doesn't save its value after an ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, textbox

I have a textbox with property TextMode = "password".
After I call a server function using ajax (PageMethods), the value is cleared from the textbox.
All the other textboxes I have (not password textboxes), saved their values.

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks,
Inbal.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520991/retain-password-field-value-on-postback

Answer (score 0):

Well its security feature which do not saves any value if you have selected `Textmode` as password however if you want to fetch this value you can save textbox value in `ViewState` .So that it can be persisted during post-back.